# Pagination in custom post type in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination, custom-post-type

I am try to put pagination in my custom post in wordpress.  my custom post type name is videos. it appears the pagination but when I click on the pagination page it goes to 404 page.

```
<?php 
$videos= new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type'=>'videos',
    'posts_per_page' => 9,

));?>


<?php if($videos->have_posts()) : ?>
    <?php while($videos->have_posts())  : $videos->the_post(); ?>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            <div class="video">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                <div class="watch">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><i class="fa fa-play"></i></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="video-exerpt">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
            </div>
        </div>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <div class="col-xs-12 text-center">
        <?php
            $GLOBALS['wp_query'] = $videos; 

            the_posts_pagination(
                array(
                    'mid_size' => '2',
                    'prev_text' => '<i class="fa fa-hand-o-left"></i> Previous',
                    'next_text' => 'Next <i class="fa fa-hand-o-right"></i>',
                    'screen_reader_text' => ' '
                    )
            );
        ?>
    </div>
<?php else :?>
    <h3><?php _e('404 Error&#58; Not Found', 'Bangladesh Parjatan'); ?></h3>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata();?>
```

[image]

its shows the pagination bt the links are not working. Please help me.

Comment: Can you show the rendered html of the pagination links as well here?

Comment: You have generated text for buttons, but you didn't generate links. Have a look at https://css-tricks.com/snippets/wordpress/paginate-custom-post-types/

Answer (score 3):

pass your wp_query arguments like this. You should use paged argument for pagination.

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
  $videos= new WP_Query(array(
                        'post_type'=>'videos',
                        'posts_per_page' => 9,
                        'paged' => $paged,
                    ));
```

hopfully your pagination will work fine.

Comment: it shows link in the button bt when  i click on 2nd page it goes to 404.php page........ 

please see the screenshot https://www.dropbox.com/s/nzu8zxz6x9yymhz/Captsldnure.JPG?dl=0

Comment: Your post type name and your page slug is same?

Comment: If same then change your page slug from your post type name.

Comment: @saift0014 did you get any solution?

Comment: @saift0014 Ok, If the answer helped please accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Can you please replace below code?

```
<?php 
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

$videos= new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type'=>'videos',
    'posts_per_page' => 9,
    'paged' => $paged,
)); ?>

<?php if($videos->have_posts()) : ?>
<?php while($videos->have_posts())  : $videos->the_post(); ?>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
    <div class="video">
        <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
        <div class="watch">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><i class="fa fa-play"></i></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="video-exerpt">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
    </div>
</div>

<?php endwhile; ?>            
    <?php 
    $total_pages = $videos->max_num_pages;

    if ($total_pages > 1){

        $current_page = max(1, get_query_var('paged'));

        echo paginate_links(array(
            'base' => get_pagenum_link(1) . '%_%',
            'format' => '/page/%#%',
            'current' => $current_page,
            'total' => $total_pages,
            'prev_text'    => __('« prev'),
            'next_text'    => __('next »'),
        ));
    }
    ?>    
<?php else :?>
<h3><?php _e('404 Error&#58; Not Found', 'Bangladesh Parjatan'); ?></h3>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata();?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```html
   

<?php 

$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

$videos= new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type'=>'videos',
    'posts_per_page' => 9,
    'paged' => $paged,
)); ?>

<?php if($videos->have_posts()) : ?>

<?php while($videos->have_posts())  : $videos->the_post(); ?>

<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4">

    <div class="video">
    
        <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
        
        <div class="watch">
        
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><i class="fa fa-play"></i></a>
            
        </div>
        
    </div>
    
    <div class="video-exerpt">
    
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
        
    </div>


<?php endwhile; ?>            
    
<?php else :?>

<h3><?php _e('404 Error&#58; Not Found', 'Bangladesh Parjatan'); ?></h3>

<?php endif; ?>

</div>

<nav>
        <ul class="pagination">
                
         <?php
                  
$big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer
echo paginate_links( array(
    'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', get_pagenum_link( $big ) ),
    'format' => '?paged=%#%',
    'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
    'total' => $the_query->max_num_pages
) );
                                    ?>
        </ul>
       </nav>

<?php wp_reset_postdata();?>
```

Comment: You might have a right answer but please explain your code when answering questions